# is it possible to use c# with google spreadsheets api version 3 - specifically to use the table and record functions?

Tags: c#, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I need to access a table that has been created by a java program on android but cannot find any .net documentation and the Java examples do not seem to match up to the libraries I have, is it possible?

thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the Spreadsheets API has been updated and includes complete samples for C#:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of your programming language requirements for what you are building, but if your open to using java to do this, Apache Poi (the Java API for Microsoft Documents) MIGHT help you accomplish this. [Apache Poi](http://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: Unfortunately I am using c# as mentioned in the question.